# String List Sort based on Integer order

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have List. This list holds integer values only though the data type is string. I want to sort the list based on integer order of the items.

How do I achieve it?

```
List<string> newZipCodesList = new List<string>();
```

Comment: If it holds integers, why aren't you using `List<int>`?

Comment: I get it from another method. I cannot change it.

Comment: The default string sorting would work just as well, without having to overhead of converting each string to an int and back.  It's much more efficient and requires less code.

Comment: Default sorting does not work..Try with the following data -- zipCodes.Add("1"); zipCodes.Add("2"); zipCodes.Add("10");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IComparer Interface to implement your own sort. You will have to create a class which will implement IComparer of T where T in this case would be string.

```
   newZipCodesList.Sort(new Test());

   public class Test : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            //return 1 when first is greater than second
            if(Convert.ToInt32(x) > Convert.ToInt32(y))
                return 1;
            //return -1 when first is less than second
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(x) < Convert.ToInt32(y))
                return -1;
            //return 0 if they are equal
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Haris you can improve it more by replacing the body inside the `Compare` method by one single line `return Convert.ToInt32(x) - Convert.ToInt32(Y);` ;)

Comment: @Jalal: this code is not about performance, it is about teaching someone something in most simplest form

Comment: @Jalal In the case of zipcodes, that change will work, but in the general case, not so much, a very large value compared to a very small value will generate an overflow one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

This is if you need to order by Integer.

```
List<string> sortedZipCodes = (from code in newZipCodesList
                               orderby Convert.ToInt32(code)
                               select code).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are using `List<string>` in the first place, but anyway you can either copy the list to int list, sort it then copy back to string, or sort the string by casting each comparer to int the compare it, or you can use API to sort strings with numerics values, but here you can use it for only numeric:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(String x, String y);
```

so:

```
newZipCodesList.Sort(StrCmpLogicalW);
```

//Test:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[] { "1", "4", "17", "5", "112", "0" });

list.Sort(StrCmpLogicalW);

//results: 0, 1, 4, 5, 17, 112
```

Comment: Can you please explain why DllImport("shlwapi.dll"? I think answer from "Haris Hasan" works. Any  different thoughts?

Comment: `Can you please explain why DllImport("shlwapi.dll"? I think answer from "Haris Hasan" works` @Lijo use @Haris answer, it is simpler in your case, I didn't added this answer as replacement to his because   I posted my answer before him. Also note that we are here providing alternatives.

Comment: Of course, I appreciate the forum and your answer. I was just double checking if there is any differences.

Comment: @Lijo: don't worry, however there is difference between the two solutions, but in your case you did not get benefit from it. that this solution is used for strings that have a combination between strings and integers and sort them probably. for example for file names like `myFile01.txt`...

Answer (score 2):

If it is safe to assume that all elements in the list are the same length (e.g. zip codes are typically 5 characters), then there is no need to call `Int.Parse()` or `Convert.ToInt()` on every single item before sorting. Even though they are represented as strings, the "alphabetic" sorting should still put them in numerical order, because "0" comes before "1" comes before "2" ...  And would be faster than performing all the conversions.

In that case, this would work:

```
List<String> zipCodes = new List<String>();
zipCodes.Add("00124");
zipCodes.Add("00123");
zipCodes.Add("98765");
zipCodes.Add("12345");
zipCodes.Add("33333");
zipCodes.Add("24680");

// zipCodes = zipCodes.Select(z => z.PadLeft(5, '0')).ToList();
zipCodes.Sort();

for(int i = 0; i < zipCodes.Count; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(zipCodes[i]);
```

And here is the output:

```
00123
00124
12345
24680
33333
98765
```

If they are not the same length, you may be able to pad them, depending on how you are using the list later. (See commented line in code).
This would convert things like `1` into `00001`

Comment: Default sorting does not work..Try with the following data --             zipCodes.Add("1");
            zipCodes.Add("2");
            zipCodes.Add("10");

Comment: @Lijo: I didn't realize that you would be considering zip codes that are not the same length.  My solution makes the assumption that every string has the same number of characters.  I made an update to the code that would handle any zip code with 5-or-less characters. It really depends on how you are using the list in your application, though.

Comment: @Lijo, if you have a zip code value of "1", I encourage you to find where the system is misusing the zip code. Don't compound the mistake by complicating algorithms elsewhere, fix the mistake where it is. A well formed zip code should never be "1". My guess is that somewhere, the program is treating it like a number. Despite being formed by digits, a zip code is *never* a numeric type and should not be treated like one.

Answer (score 0):

```
newZipCodesList.Sort( (a,b) => { 
                             int a1;
                             int a2;
                             if !(int.TryParse(a,out a1)) return 1;
                             if !(int.TryParse(b,out b1)) return -1;
                             return a1.CompareTo(b1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers can be used if the strings are all numbers. If that is not the case then have a look [here](http://madebits.com/articles/numsort/index.php) for more complex sorting.